# JQUERY + PHP POST not send a values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form with four `<input type='submit'/>` buttons and `action='updateEstado.php'`. Also, I have some jQuery code that launches when I click a button.

```
<!-- CHANGE STATUS MODAL MENU -->

<div class="modal fade" id="change" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="change" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">CANVIAR ESTAT</h3>    
            </div>

            <form action="updateEstado.php" method="post">  
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class=" text-center">

                                <div class="container-fluid">   
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                            <input type="submit" id="cambiarestado" class="btn btn-modal-estado" style="background-color:YellowGreen; color:white;" value="ACTIVAT">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                            <input type="submit" id="cambiarestado" class="btn btn-modal-estado" style="background-color:Tomato; color:white;" value="PENDENT MIQUEL ALIMENTACIÓ">          
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row ">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 text center">
                                            <input type="submit"  id="cambiarestado" class="btn btn-modal-estado" style="background-color:SkyBlue; color:white;" value="PENDENT ADDCOM">
                                        </div>  
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 text center">
                                            <input type="submit" id="cambiarestado" class="btn btn-modal-estado" style="background-color:Gray; color:white;" value="DESACTIVAT">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <h5 id='codigosSeleccionados'></h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    

                        </div>   
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>


<script>
    $('#cambiarestado').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();                     
        // Get the value of the input fields
        var inputvalue = $(this).attr("value");

        // Send Ajax request to updateEstado.php, with value set as 'input' in the POST data
        $.post("updateEstado.php", {estado: "DESACTIVAT", codigo: "38"});

        alert(inputvalue);          
    });
</script>
```

I have updated the jquery code with this new line: `event.preventDefault();`

Now when I launch the updateEstado.php the console show this message:

[image]

If I delete this line: `$.post("updateEstado2.php", {estado: "DESACTIVAT", codigo: "38"});`

The show message disappear. It's clear this is the problem. The solution¿? I do not...

Comment: You have to use unique `id` names. Instead use `class` as the trigger.

Comment: Submit buttons submit the form as is. Your jQuery code is never executed. You need to add an onsubmit function to the form itself: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp Additionally, ids must be unique.

Comment: Yes the code is executed because I can show the alert message into the jquery.

Answer (score 1):

The submit button submits the form if it isn't blocked. You can block it with `preventDefault()`.

for example:

```
$('#cambiarestado').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...rest of your code ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I put event.preventDefault(); the jquery code doesn't run when I click the button. The problem is inverse, when I click the button the jquery will run and the form input action doesn't run

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have a JS bug? This answer should work (make sure you add an event parameter to your click callback).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to submit the form via JavaScript, instead of the standard HTML form submit, you have to do several things:

1. add an onsubmit function to the form
2. use event.preventDefault() to cancel the normal form submit
3. get the values from the form
4. do a manual form submit via jQuery

BUT I think you want to do something far more trivial:
Submit two values, regardless of which option the user clicks.

The easiest way to archieve this, is to use hidden inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="estado" value="DESACTIVAT">
<input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="38">
```

Comment: I want to submit form via javascript because I have an array to sent to php form.

Comment: Probably check this out then: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Answer (score 0):

If button type is submit, when you click in the button form will be submited to `updateEstado.php` without the values of `$.post`. You can submit the form with JQuery and send the data:

```
<form id="form" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text center">
            <input type="submit" id="cambiarestado" class="btn btn-modal-estado" style="background-color:Gray; color:white;" value="DESACTIVAT">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Function:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    $.post("updateEstado.php", {estado: "DESACTIVAT", codigo: "38"});
});
```

Or, if you want to get the values of button:

```
<form id="form" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text center">
            <input type="button" id="cambiarestado" class="btn btn-modal-estado" style="background-color:Gray; color:white;" value="DESACTIVAT">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note type is button, and this way form is not submited.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var inputvalue = $(this).attr("value");          
    $.post("updateEstado.php", {estado: inputvalue, codigo: "38"});             
});
```

Comment: For testing I change the code: in action='updateEstado.php' but in the jquery code updateEstado2.php and it using your jquery function #form with $.post("updateEstado2.php") launch updateEstado.php :(

Comment: You set the id of `form` to to form? `<form id="form" action..>`